# Wordpress - Free products already purchased on signup

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, wordpress-ecommerce

I am creating a wordpress website with woocommerce for digital virtual products to be sold like PDFs, videos, MP3 files, etc.

What I am looking to do is that after a user signs up as a thank you I want to show some products to be already in their purchased list so they can directly download or access these without purchasing anything.

Can anyone please help me achieve this or suggest a plugin that will help me do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for this use case I wrote a function that automatically on signup and first login allots the products to the user.

I wrote the function to create these orders in the database directly, so the users can see it in their orders history and can download the digital products too.

Answer (score 1):

The memberships plugin from WooCommerce (written by SkyVerge) will do this.  Once a member signs up, you automatically assign them to become members of a certain class.  You can assign those free digital products to their membership class.  Memberships is a premium plugin, but it should do what you need it to do.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-restrict-content/

Comment: Okay, so membership plugin needs to be used to achieve this? This plugin is messing with my website, but I will try and use other membership plugins to see if it works. I will update here once I can achieve it.